# C++ Class expression parameter incorrect definition

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-reference

I'm learning C++ and currently experiencing weird problem with Class template.
This is my header file:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <int n>
class Vector {

public:
    list<float> coords;
    Vector();
    Vector(list<float> ncoords);
};

template <int n>
Vector<n>::Vector() {
    coords.assign(n, 0.0);
}
#endif
```

And this is my .cpp file:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <list>

using std::ostream;
using namespace std;

template <int n>
Vector<n>::Vector(list<float> ncoords): coords {ncoords}{}
```

Everything works fine if I do `Vector<2> vector;`

But linker gives an error if I try to 
`Vector<20> vector2 { list<float>{} };`

Error message

> undefined reference to `Vector<20>::Vector(std::list >)'

The question is - how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't implement templates in .cpp-Files, you have to put that in the header.

Comment: Templates have to be implemented in headers. See [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates have to be implemented inside header files. This is due to the way linking works. Read the exhaustive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056) carefully. And the next time search before asking.